# Facebook Audience Network with Too many Warnings on XCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I got a lot of warning relating to "No such file or directory" and "Could not resolve external type" when integrating FB Audience Network to my app.

[image]

This method: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921 does NOT work for me.

The only way to clear the warning is changing Debug Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) = DWARF. But I need DSym to track the crash report.

Do you guys have any solution ? if not... is it OK to ignore the warning ?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Update: I still get the same problem while building the original sample project of Facebook SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios.

Comment: I have this frustrating problem as well. Does it have something to do with my not using Cocoapods and using Swift?

Comment: You can safely use DWARF for the Debug configuration, not for Release.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings appear to be a known issue with recent Xcode versions (see http://fortheloveoftech.com/2015/06/08/apple-releases-xcode-7-beta/) - dsymutil may print warnings about unresolved external types when compiling C++ projects with precompiled headers. These should be harmless.