# Facebook SDK produces hundreds of warnings while generating DSYM information

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I updated my app with the new Crashlytics/Fabric SDK and also Facebook SDK and now i am getting hundreds of warnings while generating debug information for crashlytics.  I searched around and changed many build settings but still getting warnings.  The debug information format is set to "DWARF with dSYM" that i think is required by crashlytcs.  I have $(inherited) set in Other Linker Flags.  Bit code is set to No.  Not sure which other settings I should change to get rid of the warnings and be able to generate the proper dSYM file. I am using Xcode 7.2 and building for iOS 9.2.

Here is a warning sample:

```
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: /var/folders/h9/zf2xtlkd12z1_ygkj8hplkhh17xrbq/C/org.llvm.clang.dzhuowen/ModuleCache/1VMMO06OSVUBF/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: /var/folders/h9/zf2xtlkd12z1_ygkj8hplkhh17xrbq/C/org.llvm.clang.dzhuowen/ModuleCache/1VMMO06OSVUBF/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: /var/folders/h9/zf2xtlkd12z1_ygkj8hplkhh17xrbq/C/org.llvm.clang.dzhuowen/ModuleCache/1VMMO06OSVUBF/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: /var/folders/h9/zf2xtlkd12z1_ygkj8hplkhh17xrbq/C/org.llvm.clang.dzhuowen/ModuleCache/1VMMO06OSVUBF/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: /var/folders/h9/zf2xtlkd12z1_ygkj8hplkhh17xrbq/C/org.llvm.clang.dzhuowen/ModuleCache/1VMMO06OSVUBF/Darwin-38I6DLZ5IH61J.pcm: No such file or directory 
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSCache
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSMapTable
while processing /Users/Yan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBCache.o):
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSObject
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Audience Network with Too many Warnings on XCode 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259387/facebook-audience-network-with-too-many-warnings-on-xcode-7)

Answer (score 1):

This mean this SDK need some more files which are missing. Did you update the latest one?

By my experience I too face this issue before. I was add FBSDK alone then it shows this kind of bugs in my log., finally I found some more framework which is bolt need to add.. You can see in every files of header files in framework, search it which are present or not. This is one of the solution I found...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will check it again. I think added all the needed frameworks.  I added Bolt which was required by parse  Also if i disable creating DSYM i won't see these warnings.

Comment: Having same problem how did you fix it

Comment: I already mentioned it my answer. This issue comes under the lack of framework or any other files related to the corresponding framework. Please check the frameworks files which files are missing. In my case i missed bolt framework then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For the errors:

```
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSObject
```

The problem happens when you have a Xcode 6 project updated to 7. The short answer is to change the Debug Information Format to "DWARF", on the target, for the Debug configuration only.

- Go to Build Settings and search for Debug Information Format
- Change the Debug setting from "DWARF with dSYM File" to "DWARF"
- Leave the Release setting at "DWARF with dSYM File"

This is safe because you don't need  dSYM files for Debug builds

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `Generate Debug Symbols = No` in `Build Settings`